# how to refresh side menu in ionic / angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

after I do the login I can't get the username of the employee in the side menu and I don't know how to do it
or what I'm missing the problem is like I explain in code with comments :

I want it to refresh the app.component.ts after I get the new data

please help me

here the app.component.ts file: As you can see here I can't get the name of the employee that login to the application

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { LoginserviceService } from '../app/services/serviceLogin/loginservice.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name: string;
  responsable: boolean;
  is_Responsable_Or_Agent: string;
  constructor(private loginser: LoginserviceService) {} // this is the login service
  ngOnInit() {

    this.name = this.loginser.getArName();
    console.log(this.name)// when i console this name i got nothing
  }
}
```

here the service.ts : here I pass the name of the employee after the login to send it to the app.component.ts

```js
private ArName: string = ''; // this is the name of the employee
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  setArName(name) {  // this method to set the value of the name of the user after the login
    this.ArName = name;
  }
  getArName() {     // this method is to get the name of the user after the login
    return this.ArName; 
  }
```

here some of login.ts :As you can see in the login.ts I `console.log`  I get the value of the username  but I can't get this data in the app.component.ts

```js
 logForm() {
    console.log(this.Form.value.employeeN);
    this.Loginser.getdata(this.Form.value.DECAFFE).subscribe((res) => {
      console.log(res); 
      this.employee = res as Drafbies;//here the information of the user 
      this.Loginser.setArName(this.employee.AR_DELAFFE);//here the name of the user
      console.log('name is ' + this.Loginser.getArName());// when i console.log this line I get the name of the employee login 
      
      // but I can't get this information on app.componnt 
      
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have single page application and can't to refresh page, but you can use Observbles for subscribe changes. I think is better to have `Subject<string>` and subscribe that. in login you can `Next` that, in this solution in all of your app, you can refresh data.

Comment: can you give me a source to read it or some other hint

Comment: For your Problem `BehaviorSubject ` is good choisee. in this [link](https://medium.com/@weswhite/angular-behaviorsubject-service-60485ef064fc) you can laern it.

Comment: it's work for me [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=49QM3KkOKXs&ab_channel=techsith) and this video help me a lot to do it :D